# Is TestNG enough as a web test framework?

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-webdriver

I just moved into web testing using Selenium and have been learning Selenium WebDriver +  Java.

My question is, why do I need to build a test framework when TestNG is there?

What is there that TestNG cannot do as a framework?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing :-)

More seriously, TestNG is very popular with Selenium users for a variety of reasons, among which support for:

- Dependencies (very convenient to test pages that follow each other).
- Parameterization with `@DataProvider` (useful to test various combinations of browsers and user agents).
- Parallel tests (lets you test on multiple browsers simultaneously).

Check out the Selenium forums for more information and feel free to email the testng-users list if you have questions.

Comment: I was just wondering why employers would want you to build a custom Test framework from scratch while TestNg or JUnit is there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think TestNG is enough as a web test framework. If you are familiar of using JUnit, It is easier to switch into TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Building a custom framework may be necessary at times. 
And you can use TestNG for that. :)